# SSL - HTTPException: HTTP response '413: Request Entity Too Large' when communicating

Tags: java, apache, cxf, webservice-client, wildfly-8

I have a webservice client in Wildfly which is trying to upload a small file around 400 - 500kb, it was working fine but when I added the Client Cert Authentication logic it is complaining of

```
HTTPException: HTTP response '413: Request Entity Too Large' when communicating with
```

**What am I missing here or why did it stop working, how to fix it.**
The server implements the service using xdoclet tags. The client auth is done at apache level and not the application code.

Following is the code:

```
        String WS_URL = PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getMyServiceWsdlUrl();
        URL url = new URL(WS_URL);
        QName qname = new QName(PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getMyServiceNamespaceURI(), "MyService");

        //Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

        Service service = Service.create(qname);

        MyEndpoint myEndpointPort = service.getPort(MyEndpoint.class);
        //HACK: The underlying "JMess" changes our passed Endpoint URL with the hostname of the box (that we won't be able to find
        //      since everything is straight IP's...  So we update it again here... There has to be a better way...
        //((BindingProvider)myEndpointPort).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,WS_URL.replace("?wsdl",""));
        Map<String, Object> req_ctx = ((BindingProvider) myEndpointPort).getRequestContext();
        req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, WS_URL.replace("?wsdl",""));
        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) myEndpointPort;
        SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding) bp.getBinding();

        // Adding Client Authentication
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getServerTruststore());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getServerTruststorePassword());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getServerKeystore());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getServerKeystorePassword());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "SSL");

        Client client=ClientProxy.getClient(myEndpointPort);
        HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit)client.getConduit();
        TLSClientParameters tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();

        // Disabling host name check
        tlsParams.setDisableCNCheck(true);

        // Setup Truststore 
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        File truststore = new File(PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getServerTruststore());
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(truststore), PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getServerTruststorePassword().toCharArray()); 

        // Setting trust manager(s)
        TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = 
            TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()); 
        trustFactory.init(keyStore); 
        TrustManager[] tm = trustFactory.getTrustManagers(); 
        tlsParams.setTrustManagers(tm);

        // Setup Keystore 
        truststore = new File(PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getServerKeystore());
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(truststore), PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getServerKeystorePassword().toCharArray());

        // Setting up key manager(s)
        KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = 
            KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());                         
        keyFactory.init(keyStore, PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getServerKeystorePassword().toCharArray()); 
        KeyManager[] km = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();                      
        tlsParams.setKeyManagers(km); 

        // Setting parameters
        conduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the SSL Regeneration Buffer size in apache.
The fix was to increase the buffer size using the SSLRenegBufferSize directive,
I set it to 8MB.

```
<Location "/myws/feature/FeatureEndpoint">
    SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
    SSLRenegBufferSize 8388608
    SSLVerifyDepth 1
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} eq "Client Certificate"
</Location>
```